# What is the process that run the WEB API for ASP.NET framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I am new to C# and ASP.NET. For my uni project, I inherited a backend server that serves web api using the  dot net framework.

I want to add more API to the projects, however I cannot debug the API as breaking points are not working ( I am in debug mode). I think it might be because I didn’t attach the right process. As the API somehow runs in the background after it was built without even having to start the IIS.

I have been googling for the past few days for the process that handles the API calls but still couldn’t find it. I couldn’t debug print either, which is very frustrating.

By the way I’m running the back end with Visual Studio, MS SQL, I trigger the API using postman.

Comment: How are you running the project from Visual studio? What is the base url of API?

Comment: I am just running it on local host at the moment, the URL is localhost:50565/api . At first I clicked on the run IIS green button or the start debugging  option. However I found out that the API just run in the background even when I closed the IIS. Existing API still works. I am confused and puzzled. Seems like it just run on its own after I built it.

Comment: So when you press F5 in visual studio to start the API, doesn't it hit any debug break point? Does it open any browser window?

Comment: When I start it, the IIS will run a content management system website to manage the back end. No breakpoints works. BTW thank you so so much for your help!!!

Comment: Is the content management website and web API I'm the same project?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yeah the project contains an admin console, Web API plus the CMS all in one.

Answer (score 0):

go to the project properties and create virtual directory.  Then go into IIS and add the application (based on the virtual directory. you created in visual studios.)